# Page is still refreshing even after using event.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to put form data into local storage but form is kept on refreshing even after using event.preventDefault(); and there is one error which also get refreshed in less then 1 second unable to see the error.

```html
<form id="form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td><label for="Chest">Chest</label></td>
      <td class="checkboxContainer">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkDay()" name="Monday" class="button">
      </td>
    </tr>
    . . .
    <tr>
      <td>Sunday</td>
      <td><label for="Rest">Rest</label></td>
      <td class="checkboxContainer">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkDay()" name="Sunday" class="button">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>


<script>
  let form = document.getElementById('form').submit();

  form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {

    event.preventDefault();

  })
</script>
```

Edited:

Ok so i was doing one simple mistake i was putting submit(); result in variable which is undefined so what i did is remove the submit() function.

```
  const form = document.getElementById('form');
```

and create a submit button instead of using submit(); which i don't want so i did this but again the code is not working

```
  const form = document.getElementById('form');
  document.getElementById('form').submit();
```

Comment: You're setting `form` to the result of calling the `submit` method, which is undefined. Just  use `const form = document.getElementById('form');`

Comment: Your `form` variable is not the form itself. You need to call `preventDefault` on the **form**, not on the result of the `submit()` event

Comment: It worked by replacing  let form = document.getElementById('form').submit(); with  const form = document.getElementById('form'); button now how do i submit the form without using button

Comment: Just call `form.submit();` under your `const form = [...]` line

Comment: I did @Oskar Laska but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

#### This submit is not a submit event

There is a problem with the `form` variable: the submit return is being assigned to it, it is not the form element. However, there is another point: the `HTMLFormElement.submit()` method actually does not raise any submit event.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit):

> This method is similar, but not identical to, activating a form's submit . When invoking this method directly, however:
>
> - No submit event is raised. In particular, the form's onsubmit event handler is not run.

#### You do not need the submit event

Since you are just trying to get the form data to put into local storage, you do not actually need the submit event. You could just get the data with the [FormData constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData):

```html
<form id="form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td><label for="Chest">Chest</label></td>
      <td class="checkboxContainer">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkDay()" name="Monday" class="button" checked>
      </td>
    </tr>
    . . .
    <tr>
      <td>Sunday</td>
      <td><label for="Rest">Rest</label></td>
      <td class="checkboxContainer">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkDay()" name="Sunday" class="button">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>


<script>
  let form = document.getElementById('form');
  let formData = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form));
  console.log(formData)
</script>
```